# SQL Queries inside query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns `main_article`, `sub_article`, `qty`. I can have one `main_article` that can have as `sub_article` one article that can also be in the table as `main_article`

```
main_article | sub_article| qty
-------------+------------+----
20           |     4      |  15
20           |     6      |  14
22           |     4      |  12
22           |    33      |  2
22           |    20      |  10
```

I need to get the values for `main_article` 22 with the `sub_articles` of the `main_article` 20 with the quantities of the `sub_articles` multiplied by the qty of 10 given a table like the next one.

```
main_article | sub_article| qty
-------------+------------+-----
22           |      4     |  150
22           |      6     |  140
22           |      4     |  12
22           |     33     |  2
```

I have tried several approaches with `JOIN`, `SELECT FROM` all unsuccessful.

I can get the value of the `main_article` which has `sub_articles` with:

```sql
select 
    ac.main_article, ac.sub_article, ac.qty 
from 
    compose_articles ac 
where 
    ac.main_article in (select ac2.subarticle from compose_articles ac2);
```

And get the values from the sub article by

```sql
select * 
from compose_articles ac 
where sub_article in (select ac2.main_article from compose_articles ac2);
```

Comment: Please update your question with the queries you have tried.

Comment: Please update your question, not add additional information in comments

Comment: sorry, fist time here asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, first extract main articles which are sub-articles then calculate the quantities. Finally select from main table and exclude main/sub articles which are sub articles. Below query will help

```
WITH sub_articles AS(
    SELECT main_article, sub_article,qty FROM compose_articles 
    WHERE sub_article IN (SELECT main_article FROM compose_articles)
),
calculated_subarticles AS (
    SELECT a.main_article,b.sub_article, a.qty * b.qty as qty FROM sub_articles a
    JOIN compose_articles b ON a.sub_article = b.main_article
)
SELECT * FROM compose_articles 
WHERE main_article NOT IN (SELECT sub_article FROM sub_articles) 
AND sub_article NOT IN (SELECT sub_article FROM sub_articles)
UNION
SELECT * FROM calculated_subarticles
```